# How to store list of items in MySql database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I have created a dropdown list of cities in HTML and from that list I want to display in div.

I applied onchange event on select tag and write append function in javaScript. So when any user select cities then city name should be added or get appended in the div.

I used Ajax and get city list as a response. All these things are done.

But I am facing an issue where I need to store all those city name in my database.
[![The image attached is to show my dropdown list data[![Another image is to show how data looks like when selecting any city name from dropdown][1]][1]][2]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mlEq.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVEXm.png
How should we implement this thing in JavaScript? 

Any suggestion would be appreciated.
JavaScript function to get list of cities selected from list.
function setdeliverycity(){
        var userid = document.getElementById('vendordeliveryid').value;
        var delivercityid = document.getElementById('vendorcitydd').value;
        var url = "../api/setdeliverycity";
        $.post(url,{
            userid : userid,
            delivercityid : delivercityid,
        }, function(data, status) {
            if (data.status == "OK") {
                if (data.statusCode == 1) {
                    var citydiv = "";   
                    var citylist = data.response.city;
                    var cityid = data.response.delivercityid;
                    var citylistlength = citylist.length;
                    if(citylistlength > 0) {
                        citydiv = citydiv+"<div>"+citylist+" &nbsp;<i class=\"fa fa-times\" onclick=\"removecity('"+cityid+"', '"+citylist+"')\"></i></div>";
                    }else{
                        citydiv = citydiv+"<div style=\"text-align: center; float: left; margin-left: 40%; font-size: medium; font-weight: bolder; background: blanchedalmond;\"><span>Choose city from list</span></div>";
                    }
                    $('#citydivid').append(citydiv);
                } else {
                    var error = data.responseMessage;
                    swal(error, "", "error");
                }
            } else {
                var error = data.responseMessage;
                swal(error, "", "error");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Keep these saved in local javascript array variable or in hidden input type and on same time when you are appending it in the div. i.e. on OnClick function itself. then while submitting form send this in the post body

Comment: Could you please show some as an example?

Comment: Shall I show you my script?

Comment: It would be easy if you are able to add some code here

Comment: I think, I cannot show you whole script in comment section.

Comment: I have updated my query. If possible please check.

Answer (score 0):

The sample has been added you can understand as follow.

```js
let selectedValues = [];

$(document).ready(()=>{
  $("#selectBox").change((item)=>{
    selectedValues.push($("#selectBox").val());
    $("#selectedVal").append("<div>"+$("#selectBox").val()+"</div>");
  })
  
  $("submitBtn").click(()=>{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: selectedValues,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectBox">
<option value="abc">ABC</option>
<option value="xyz">XYZ</option>
<option value="pqr">PQR</option>
<option value="ghi">GHI</option>
</select>


<div id="selectedVal">

</div>

<button type="button" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Okay. I'll try this way.